# How to understand the "Assertion failed" error in openCV?

Tags: opencv

I have got the following error while i was trying to create ROI from the original image. I understand the meaning of error (i mean, i understand the reason). **But i don't understand, which line of my code is giving me this error?** In my whole code there are several places where i creating ROI from original frame.

***Error:***

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <=      m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.6-3precise-20140130-1854/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'


 what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.6-3precise-20140130-1854/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:323: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know which line of your code the exception is being thrown, unless you do something to find it, such as:

1. Use a debugger and break at every line that uses an ROI
2. Put a [Try-Catch](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#error-handling) block around each line that uses an ROI and write out the error.

From experience using ROIs, it is likely that you are trying to subset an image with an ROI somewhere, and you are running out of bounds. OR Your ROI is of size 0,0.

Answer (score 2):

Run your code in the debugger and see where this fails, or check the stack trace to see what function this was called from.

Or if you can't do that, put a `printf("ok1");` etc in front of each roi call.

Comment: hmm but there is no way to know the line which is giving trouble from that error?